# Jupyter Notebook markdown cell is not working

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, markdown

I am using Jupyter notebook for the first time.

When I write `##Heart Disease` or `#Heart Disease` and change the cell type to markdown and run the cell nothing happens.There is no change and the text remains as it is with the hashtags.

Why is this happening?Am I supposed to install something?

Comment: ...those aren't _hashtags_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it may seem trivial, I believe the solution is putting a space between the hashtags and the text.

Comment: Thanks it works!I thought it was a really big problem.Glad it wasn't.